# Transmitting pulses via RS485

Tags: rs485

I will have an IR led / photo transistor based reflective sensor, measuring rotation speed of a wheel, producing pulses using a comparator with hysteresis. The pulses will be counted by micro-controller.

The problem is, the sensor has to be ~20m away from micro-controller and a big induction motor might be near the cable.

So, I thought - what if I put a couple of RS485 transceivers on both ends of a cable, drive a Driver Input pin on the sensor side and connect Receiver Output to the micro-controller external interrupt pin? Is this a proper solution to my problem?

Comment: The pluse will bump back when it reaches cable ends.
So you better connect termination resistors on both ends.

I have a very pain experience on this issue.

Comment: Yep this will work fine. All you want is differential signal where both lines will be effected the same, use a twisted pair cable of course.

Comment: Do you also intend to deliver power to the sensor over the same cable? If so that would add some additional wires to the cable assembly. If there is already power available at the sensor end then do plan to provide a ground wire in your cable to help control the maximum common mode voltage between the sensor end and the MCU end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that will work fine. Technically, it's RS-422 if the transmission is one-way, with the driver always enabled like this. Be sure to put a termination resistor across the receiver input pins.

Comment: Is RS-422 one-way???

Comment: @stevenvh From  wikipedia `Available Signals Tx+, Tx-, Rx+, Rx-`  **(Full Duplex )** ;)

Comment: RS-422 is an electrical specification in which a differential pair of wires is used to transmit a signal in one direction (compare with RS-423). Yes, you can use RS-422 to build a full-duplex interface, but that requires two pairs of wires. RS-485 uses essentially the same electrical specification, but transmits two directions on the same pair of wires by enabling and disabling the driver at each end as needed.